# How to insert JSON format into dataProvider using amcharts library with mySql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, amcharts, amstock

I want to do the same thing as here but with the data extracted from mySQL database and using amCharts library, so here is a snap from the code used to extract data.

The file **data.php**

```
<?php
include("include/connexion.php");
$requete = "SELECT * from table";
$resultat = mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
$total_vue = 0 ;
$rows = array(); 
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultat ) ) {
  $rows[] = $data;
  $varr = $data[ 'date' ];
  $total_vue += $data[ 'temps' ];
  $timestamp = strtotime( $varr );
  $date = date( "m-d-Y", $timestamp );  
  $time = date( "G-i-s", $timestamp );
}
?>
```

So I have extracted all data in `$rows`.

In my database, I have 3 columns:

```
id    : int(11) with AUTO_INCREMENT,
temps : int(11) ,
date  : timestamp
```

I was able to print data into a chart by following this [amcharts tutorial : using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/)

To display the data we need something like that:

```
"dataLoader": {
  "url": "json_encode.php"
},
```

The file : **json_encode.php** contains:

```
<?php
include( "data.php" );
echo  json_encode( $rows );
?>
```

The data extracted is in JSON format.

The chart was simple so I want something more advanced. I found this [amcharts demo : multiple-data-sets](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/)

Here is a snap of the code:

```
var chartData1 = [
  { country: "Czech Republic", litres: 156.90},
  { country: "Ireland", litres: 131.10},
  { country: "Germany", litres: 115.80},
  { country: "Australia", litres: 109.90},
  { country: "Austria", litres: 108.30},
  { country: "UK", litres: 99.00}
];
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  type: "stock",
  "theme": "light",
 dataSets: [ {
      title: "first data set",
      fieldMappings: [ {
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "volume",
        toField: "volume"
      } ],
      dataProvider: chartData1,
      categoryField: "date"
    }]
});
```

So to conclude, I want to **insert "json_encode.php" in dataProvider** but I haven't found a way to do it.

Something like:

```
"dataProvider": {
    "url": "json_encode.php"
},
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

update :

> FIRST

file json_encode.php when loaded shows

```
[{"id":"1","temps":"5","date":"2015-08-17 02:00:00"},{"id":"2","temps":"12","date":"2015-08-17 07:00:00"},{"id":"3","temps":"8","date":"2015-08-17 12:17:11"},{"id":"4","temps":"18","date":"2015-08-17 16:22:00"},{"id":"5","temps":"6","date":"2015-08-18 19:40:42"},{"id":"20","temps":"2","date":"2015-08-18 11:22:32"},{"id":"25","temps":"20","date":"2015-08-18 12:21:00"},{"id":"26","temps":"9","date":"2015-08-18 16:00:00"},{"id":"30","temps":"15","date":"2015-04-18 00:00:00"},{"id":"31","temps":"12","date":"2015-01-18 00:00:00"},{"id":"33","temps":"18","date":"2014-10-18 00:00:00"},{"id":"34","temps":"6","date":"2014-07-18 00:00:00"},{"id":"44","temps":"14","date":"2015-08-17 18:24:00"},{"id":"88","temps":"19","date":"2015-08-19 00:00:00"},{"id":"100","temps":"12","date":"2015-08-18 04:00:00"},{"id":"102","temps":"18","date":"2015-08-18 10:00:00"},{"id":"103","temps":"26","date":"2015-08-18 19:00:00"},{"id":"104","temps":"4","date":"2015-08-18 20:00:00"},{"id":"105","temps":"0","date":"2015-08-18 15:25:20"},{"id":"106","temps":"1","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:00"},{"id":"107","temps":"1","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:08"},{"id":"108","temps":"3","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:14"},{"id":"109","temps":"1","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:17"},{"id":"110","temps":"8","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:27"},{"id":"111","temps":"3","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:32"},{"id":"112","temps":"5","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:39"},{"id":"113","temps":"8","date":"2015-08-18 16:17:49"},{"id":"114","temps":"10","date":"2015-08-18 16:18:02"},{"id":"115","temps":"21","date":"2015-08-18 16:18:27"},{"id":"116","temps":"1","date":"2015-08-18 16:18:30"},{"id":"117","temps":"7","date":"2015-08-18 16:18:39"},{"id":"118","temps":"5","date":"2015-08-18 16:18:46"},{"id":"119","temps":"18","date":"2015-08-18 16:19:07"},{"id":"120","temps":"8","date":"2015-08-18 16:19:17"},{"id":"121","temps":"1","date":"2015-08-18 16:19:20"},{"id":"122","temps":"3","date":"2015-08-18 16:19:36"},{"id":"123","temps":"3","date":"2015-08-18 16:19:41"}]
```

with using dataLoader like @martynasma suggests i get the chart but without any data : it's seems that the date was well extracted but i don't get any datat (NB: i used data.php that i have put above)

[image: charts loaded successfully but not the DATA]

> SECOND

, when changing data.php to what @martynasma have suggested the charts still loaded but without any data or date ..

the file json_encode.php shows

```
[{"date":1439769600,"value":"5"},{"date":1439787600,"value":"12"},{"date":1439806631,"value":"8"},{"date":1439821320,"value":"18"},{"date":1439919642,"value":"6"},{"date":1439889752,"value":"2"},{"date":1439893260,"value":"20"},{"date":1439906400,"value":"9"},{"date":1429308000,"value":"15"},{"date":1421535600,"value":"12"},{"date":1413583200,"value":"18"},{"date":1405634400,"value":"6"},{"date":1439828640,"value":"14"},{"date":1439935200,"value":"19"},{"date":1439863200,"value":"12"},{"date":1439884800,"value":"18"},{"date":1439917200,"value":"26"},{"date":1439920800,"value":"4"},{"date":1439904320,"value":"0"},{"date":1439907420,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907428,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907434,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907437,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907447,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907452,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907459,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907469,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907482,"value":"10"},{"date":1439907507,"value":"21"},{"date":1439907510,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907519,"value":"7"},{"date":1439907526,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907547,"value":"18"},{"date":1439907557,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907560,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907576,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907581,"value":"3"}]
```

it seems that there is something wrong with the date

[image: charts loaded but with no data and date showing 1970 !!!]

now i have added some data into mySql
This is the data 
[image: DATA captured from mySql database]

this is what  i get , i'm happy that some data gets out but it not what i want

[image: only some data that i have added recently appears]

@martynasma ok i have updated minPeriod and timestamps but i still don't get the right date , note that json_encode.php contains something like `{"date":1439769600,"value":"5"}` the date field it's NOT CORRECT and that's why in the page that loaded i get  `1970-01-17 00:00` ... i think that mySql set the date like this if it does not found the right date
No i have searched to resolve the date format and i was able to get the right value by a little modification of your code

```
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultat ) ) {
   $rows[] = array(
    "date" =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $data['date'])  ),
    "value" => $data[ 'temps' ]
  );
}
```

after that the page loaded with the correct date but still don't get the data and the charts is looking weird now

[image: chart with exact date but the panel disapeard]

you can see that in the zoom panel **i only get 1 hour and Max** and the others disapered and i don't know why

**here what it should look like** , this capture if from the second data like i have found from the tutorial
[image: the original charts from amcharts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Data Loader in Stock Chart, you need to add `dataLoader` block into your data set definition. I.e.:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "dataSets": [ {
    "title": "first data set",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "categoryField": "date",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "json_encode.php"
    }
  } ],
  // the rest of your Stock Chart config
  // ...
} );
```

There's a section about it in [Data Loader doc](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader#using-in-javascript-stock-chart).

Having said that, your PHP script that produces JSON data, does not seem to be setup for the fields that are defined in your data set's `fieldMappings`.

Furthermore, it separates date and time into separate fields. The Stock Chart can't read dates and time from separate fields, so you need to have one.

I suppose your PHP script can be remade like this:

```
<?php
$requete = "SELECT * from table";
$resultat = mysql_query( $requete ) or die( mysql_error() );
$rows = array(); 
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultat ) ) {
  $rows[] = array(
    "date" => strtotime( $data[ 'date' ] ) * 1000,
    "value" => $data[ 'temps' ]
  );
}
echo json_encode( $rows );
?>
```

The following should produce JSON, that should work with the chart config you have.

Note that I multiply date by 1000, because PHP timestamp is in seconds, whilst JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds.

Also, it seems you have a hourly data. You will need to set [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) in `categoryAxesSettings` to "hh" so the chart knows it's not daily data. I.e.:

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
  "minPeriod": "hh",
  // the rest of your category axes settings
  // ...
}
```

As a final note, PHP MySQL extension is deprecated. Consider switching to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php), which is correct way to access MySQL data base in modern PHP environments.

Comment: thanks but this seems not working , the problem i think come from here  `"dataProvider": {
      "url": "json_encode.php"
    }`    it doesn't work

Comment: My bad. It should be `dataLoader`, not `dataProvider`. Updated the answer.

Comment: i have done ... now the chart appear but without any data ... i have updated the question and added some captures that shows the problem , please take a look , thanks :)

Comment: Updated my answer again. Added a note about PHP/JavaScript timestamps (note the change in PHP code) as well as the note about `minPeriod`.

Comment: i have added what you said , and make some change of the code , now i'm getting the date but now data is displayed and the zoom panel goes away , please take a look at the updated question , thanks :)

Comment: Don't convert the timestamps back into date strings in PHP, just multiply it by 1000. I just updated PHP code in my answer. (I had value multipled there not timestamp :)

Comment: ok it works for the data but still can't get data and still the zoom bar  not apearing .... you have said something about **fieldMappings** i didn't understund what changes should i make .... you can find here all the files http://www.filedropper.com/mysqljson

Comment: It seems you haven't implemented my latest changes in data.php

Comment: yes i have made the changes .... here what i have now 
` while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultat ) ) {
  $total_vue+=$data['temps'];
   $rows[] = array(
    "date" =>  strtotime( $data['date']) * 1000,
    "value" => $data[ 'temps' ]
  ); `   .... the file uploaded before i have viewed your latest answer

Comment: please how can i check that     ` "dataLoader": {
      "url": "json_encode.php"
    }`    has got the right data

Comment: I suppose you're not setting your data granularity correctly. It appears you have a data in seconds, so you need to set `minPeriod` to "ss" in `categoryAxesSettings`

Comment: the mySql capture shows that the data is correctly loaded :p setting minPeriod to "ss"  has no effect for me ...  if i remove minPeriod i still get correct data from the other charts

Comment: Finally that worked , you were right i have added some values manually to the database for the test and the datas was not sorted .... and in their site that  `the data sets need to come pre-ordered in ascending order.. Data with incorrect order might result in visual and functional glitches on the chart.`

Comment: no that it's working ,i have tried something different to compare and choose the best but i have an issue please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105687/how-to-get-the-data-using-dataloader-in-amcharts?noredirect=1#comment52108201_32105687